# Compile error: Argument not optional in VBA call

Tags: vba, module, call

I'm trying to hide or show connector elbows based on a value. My worksheet links to "Module1", however it gives me the compile error: Argument not optional. I've made it work, working only in the worksheet, but cannot make it work using multiple different modules.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
        If Target.Address = "$B$48" Then
        
            If Target.Value = 1 Then
                Call Route1
            If Target.Value = 2 Then
                Call Route2
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Module1:

```
Sub Route1(ByVal Target As Range)
        Shapes.Range(Array("Connector: Elbow 137")).Line.Visible = msoTrue
        Shapes.Range(Array("Connector: Elbow 142")).Line.Visible = msoFalse
        Shapes.Range(Array("Connector: Elbow 143")).Line.Visible = msoTrue
End Sub
```

Module2:

```
Sub Route2(ByVal Target As Range)
    Shapes.Range(Array("Connector: Elbow 137")).Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shapes.Range(Array("Connector: Elbow 142")).Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shapes.Range(Array("Connector: Elbow 143")).Line.Visible = msoFalse
End Sub
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: Get rid of `ByVal Target As Range` in `Route1` and `Route2`.

Comment: It got ride of the compile error, however how it gives me "Run-time error '424': Object required" on Elbow 137. It doesn't seem to recognize the elbow connector although the figure itself is called 137? The worksheet is a copy of the original excel file that I test in, but that should not have an effect on the elbows since they're called the same?

Comment: I think you need a worksheet object before `Shapes`.

Comment: Aside from what @BigBen said your Change_Event is missing an `End If` - 3 x `If` and 2 x `End If`

Comment: Unless your `If Target.Value = 2` should read `ElseIf Target.Value = 2`?

Comment: Hi @DarrenBartrup-Cook + BigBen
Thanks tons for the feedback. Else.if target solved the issue as well as adding the worksheet object. Thanks again everyone :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the "Route1/2" method from the worksheet module, where the implicit context is the worksheet itself, but the called methods are in regular modules, where the implicit "worksheet" context is the ActiveSheet (hence @BigBen's comment above).

Might be easier to handle this all in the worksheet module:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$48" Then ShowRoute Target.Value
End Sub

Sub ShowRoute(RouteNum)
    Select Case RouteNum
        Case 1, 2:
            Me.Shapes("Connector: Elbow 137").Line.Visible = IIf(RouteNum = 1, msoTrue, msoFalse)
            Me.Shapes("Connector: Elbow 142").Line.Visible = msoFalse
            Me.Shapes("Connector: Elbow 143").Line.Visible = IIf(RouteNum = 1, msoTrue, msoFalse)
        Case Else:
            '?
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Tim William 
Thanks a lot for the feedback. It solves my challenge. The issue however, is a need to add +19 different "cases", along with +30 different connectors and thus an easy way to do it was to just keep adding "Elseifs" and additional modules. While additional modules solves my problem I'm sure a much easier solution could be made using loops like your suggestion :-)
Thanks again

Comment: If it's a complex set of rules then you could consider setting those up in a table on  a worksheet - cases as rows and connector names as columns, then an "X" for visible for example.  Difficult to say without a more elaborated example of what you need to do.